# Convert VB.NET Encrypt/Decript old code to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption

I am trying to convert VB.NET Encrypt/Decrypt to PHP. The issue is we can not update the PHP version and the server supports only PHP5.3

VB.NET Sample Output Link
http://www.tattoogenda.com/LoginTest.aspx

VB.NET Output is: Ao5ZnFYo344iWqv/Jr9euw==

PHP OutPut is: NzmRRxTaXgWFIPx/SqODog==
VB.NET Code as below:

```vb
Public Shared Function Encrypt(clearText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
    Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D,
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65,
         &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return clearText
End Function
Public Shared Function Decrypt(cipherText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
    Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D,
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65,
         &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return cipherText
End Function
```

PHP Test link Output:
http://www.tattoogenda.com/app-api/logintest.php

PHP Code:

```
<?php

include_once('PBKDF2.php');
use PBKDF2\PBKDF2;

function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
    $output = false;

$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
//$encrypt_method = "AES-128-CBC";
$secret_key = 'MAKV2SPBNI99212';

$secret_iv=chr(0x49).chr(0x76).chr(0x61).chr(0x6e).chr(0x20).chr(0x4d).chr(0x65).chr(0x64).chr(0x76).chr(0x65).chr(0x64).chr(0x65).chr(0x76);
   
$generated_key =  PBKDF2::deriveKey("sha256", $secret_key, $secret_iv, 20000, 128, true, false);

$key = substr($generated_key, 0, 32);;
//$key = substr(hash('sha1', $secret_key), 0, 32);;
echo "key: ".$key."<br>";

$iv = substr($generated_key, 0, 16);
//$iv = substr(hash('sha1', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
echo "iv key: ".$iv."<br>";
if( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
   
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv );
    $output = base64_encode($output);
}
else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key,  $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}

return $output;
}

$plain_txt = "1234";
echo "Plain Text = $plain_txt\n"."<br/>";
$plain_txt = mb_convert_encoding($plain_txt, "UTF-8" , "UTF-16LE");
echo "Encoded Plain Text = $plain_txt\n"."<br/>";

$encrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $plain_txt);
echo "Encrypted Text = $encrypted_txt\n"."<br/>";

$decrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted_txt);
echo "Decrypted Text = $decrypted_txt\n"."<br/>";

if( $plain_txt === $decrypted_txt ) echo "SUCCESS"."<br/>";
else echo "FAILED"."<br/>";

echo "\n"."<br/>";
```

?>

Comment: Okay, thank you and can you let me know how can that be fit? I mean what need to be changed?

Comment: @user9014097 - correct I can not use openssl_pbkdf2 and hash_pbkdf2. Do you know any alternative library for PHP5.3?

Comment: Just a note: the newest phpseclib (version 3) runs on **minimum PHP version: 5.6.1** so you need to use phpseclib **version 2**

Comment: @user9014097 Thank you! Yes, I will stick with openssl and will check that PBKDf2 and let you know,

Comment: @user9014097 - I updated my code of PHP as you suggested...but the output is still not the same: I am getting the following output in PHP now. I set the encoding of the text as well as used PBKDF2 to get key and iv...would you please check and let me what the issue could be now? The php out put is:  k/b0uA4971w0WnVkSja27w==

Comment: @user9014097 - Also someone told me that I should use ACE 128 and sh1 as per my VB.NET code instead of ACE-256 and sha256 is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VB code uses a 32 bytes key so in the PHP code `AES-256-CBC` is correct. Also `Rfc2898DeriveBytes()` applies an iteration count of 1000 by default (and SHA1 as digest), which must therefore also be used in the PHP code. Since the VB code derives both, the 32 bytes key and the IV, 32 + 16 must be specified as size in the PHP code:

```php
$generated_key =  PBKDF2::deriveKey("sha1", $secret_key, $secret_iv, 1000, 32+16, true, false);
```

Of the returned result, the first 32 bytes are the key, the following 16 bytes are the IV:

```php
$key = substr($generated_key, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($generated_key, 32, 16);
```

$`key` and $`iv` are to be used *directly* in `openssl_encrypt()/decrypt()`, i.e. the explicit hashing with SHA1 is to be removed for key and IV.

The passed plaintext must be UTF-16LE encoded before encryption (either inside or outside of `encrypt_decrypt()`), e.g. with

```php
$string =  mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-16le', 'utf-8');
```

Note that the start encoding is the third parameter and the destination encoding is the second parameter.

An encryption of `Hello Asif` returns `1N1U0Oy81PGOm/Yqdp9sT5iyPgPFxsc8Q8mADNa8BzQ=` in accordance with the VB code.

For decryption, the procedure is analogous.

Note that for security reasons the salt (denoted here as `$secret_iv`) should be *randomly* generated for *each* key derivation. The salt is not secret and can be sent along with the ciphertext (usually concatenated). Also, an iteration count of 1000 is generally too small for PBKDF2.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thank you so much you made my day :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$text = "hello";
$enc = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($enc, $mode), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$keys = array();
// smaller than 128 bit key gets padded to 128 bit
$keys[] = pack('H*', "00112233445566778899aabbccddee");
$keys[] = pack('H*', "00112233445566778899aabbccddee00");
// larger than 128 bit key gets padded to 192 bit
$keys[] = pack('H*', "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00");
$keys[] = pack('H*', "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff0000000000000000");
// larger than 192 bit key gets padded to 256 bit
$keys[] = pack('H*', "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff001122334455667700");
$keys[] = pack('H*', "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566770000000000000000");
// larger than 256 bit key will be truncated (with a warning)
$keys[] = pack('H*', "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00");
foreach ($keys as $key)
{ echo base64encode(mcrypt_encrypt($enc, $key, $text, $mode, $iv))."\n";
}
```

Comment: You should explain the posted code a little bit. I don't see compatibility with the VB code here. Also, mcrypt is deprecated (already from PHP 5.3 e.g. openssl is supported).